# Get oldest modified price

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table where each rows contains product id (A), price (P) and modification date (D) in YYYYMMDD format.

Here is the table :

```
WITH temp_table AS (
select 744583 as a, 9.21 as p, 20210706 as d from sysibm.sysdummy1
union all
select 744583 as a, 9.21 as p, 20210630 as d from sysibm.sysdummy1
union all
select 744583 as a, 9.21 as p, 20210628 as d from sysibm.sysdummy1
union all
select 744583 as a, 9.04 as p, 20210604 as d from sysibm.sysdummy1
union all
select 744583 as a, 9.04 as p, 20210201 as d from sysibm.sysdummy1
union all
select 744583 as a, 9.21 as p, 20200407 as d from sysibm.sysdummy1
)
select *
from temp_table
```

[what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INRzq.png)

What i would like to have is when the price changed for the last time. In this example, the third line :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DH0o.png)

How would you do that ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `lag()` and then ordering:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(p) over (order by d desc) as prev_p
      from temp_table  t
     ) t
where prev_p is null or prev_p <> p
order by d desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

If you wanted to do this for multiple `a`s at the same time, then there are different approaches.  An interesting one uses a difference of row numbers:

```
select a, p, min(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a order by date desc) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by a, p order by date desc) as seqnum_2
      from temp_table t
     ) t
where seqnum = seqnum_2
group by a, p;
```

You can investigate why this works.  The two row numbers are the same only for the last price for each `a`.